# PHP reset first level of an array without loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple multidimensional array like the following

```
$array = array(
    array('key1'=>array('a','b')),
    array('key2'=>array('c','d'), 'key3'=>array('e','f')),
    array('key4'=>array('g','h'), 'key5'=>array('i','j'), 'key6'=>array('k','l', 'm'))
);
```

and I would reset its first level like the following

```
$array = array(
    'key1'=>array('a','b'),
    'key2'=>array('c','d'),
    'key3'=>array('e','f'),
    'key4'=>array('g','h'),
    'key5'=>array('i','j'),
    'key6'=>array('k','l','m')
);
```

I know it's quite easy with a `foreach` loop to achieve, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it using one line code.

What I tried so far

```
array_map('key', $array);
```

but it returns only the first key of child array.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well I would suggest you give it a try and then ask for help if you cannot get it to work

Comment: give it a try DrKey

Comment: is the reason just to try or learn other ways to do things? Because the array_map would need approx. a comparable char count than a loop. (you can write such loops in one line too)

Comment: `call_user_func_array('array_merge',$array)`

Comment: I don't think a downvote would be necessary, just ask..

Comment: foreach with array_map sounds a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.6 introduce the variadic functions in PHP, which allow one to write funtions that take any additional argument into the same array using the splat operator : `...` .

The other - maybe fairly less known - use of that operator is that it works the other way around. By placing that operator before an array in a function's call, it makes that function to take the entries of that array as if you wrote them *inline*.

Which allows you to type :

```
$array = array_merge(... $array);
```

Sending $array would usually return $array unchanged. Using the splat makes `array_merge` to work on the undefined amount of 2nd level arrays in it. Since array_merge is itself a variadic function that merge any arrays you send to it, it works.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't even know the _splat_ operator.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try this: made it work with `array_reduce`.

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function($final, $value) {
    return array_merge($final, $value);
}, array());
```

[online example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7ff96f3207b86c1677cea7b1bfd3f181e13b72d)